# Win RT: Caller does not have the EnterpriseAuthentication capability

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I have Windows Store Application (Win RT) and I need to get the current user domain name.  Here is my code:

```
name = await Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetDomainNameAsync();
```

But I get exception:

```
Win RT:  Caller does not have the EnterpriseAuthentication capability
```

What I need to do to fix it, if I don't have physical device and working in VS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the [UserInformation.NameAccessAllowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.nameaccessallowed) flag before calling the GetDomainNameAsync method?

UPDATE 1: To access the domain name you have to add Enterprise Authentication capability in manifest. Based on the [UserInformation.GetDomainNameAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getdomainnameasync.aspx) documentation, It can be empty when the privacy settings related to account info access turned 'Off'. You can check for the privacy settings in your machine's PC settings: [image: Privacy Settings]

Comment: Have you enabled Enterprise Authentication capability in manifest? [about capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it helps and I don't have the exception now.  But GetDomainNameAsync() returns the empty string.  How can I fix it ?